# BizTalk maps that rely on configuration data?

Tags: testing, configuration, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have a simple BizTalk map that uses a scripting functoid to call an external assembly function. This function, however, relies on a value from configuration. For a live server, this config file is BTSNTSvc.exe.config, but what file is used when testing a map in Visual Studio?

I have attempted to place Debug.WriteLine calls in my external assembly to trace out the location of the configuration file, but nothing appears in my trace listener, either.

I need to maintain the ability to switch values in config, but I'd also like to retain the short turnaround time afforded by testing in VS, rather than having to fully deploy every time. Is this possible?

Comment: First, does it really have to work this way?  Do you own that library?  Using a .config for an integration app is something you should avoid.

Comment: Based on my current perspective, it does need to be this way; however, I'm open to suggestions. Can you explain why that's something I should avoid? My motivation is that we want to use configuration to point test systems away from production systems for isolation/protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that would be the devenv.exe.config.

C:\Program Files(x86)\VSVersion\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

Another way would be to make a unit test for the map instead of using the "Test Map"-functionality.

Comment: devenv.exe worked! I'd normally jump at the unit testing solution too, however it seems as though BizTalk will always fully rebuild the test project and its dependencies for each test run, which is a huge time expenditure, so I test only using "Test Map" and well as in deployment on test servers.